# Dropdown checkboxes not toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtmlx

I have a comboboxes created using DHTMLXCombo for my Gantt filter. but for some reason when I added the attach event, it stopped toggling. can anyone tell me what's the problem here, any help is much appreciated

below is my code :

HTML

```
<body onload="multiselect_filter()">
<select id="search_type" mode="checkbox" style="display:inline-block;">
    <option value="ALL" checked="1">ALL</option><option value="ALL" checked="0">ALL</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Javascript :

```
var search_type_combobox;
var search_type_value = {'ALL': true};
//FILTER BY TYPE
function multiselect_filter(){

    //SEARCH TYPE
    search_type_combobox = dhtmlXComboFromSelect("search_type", "combo", 100, "checkbox");
    search_type_combobox.enableFilteringMode(true);

//IT STOP TOGGLING WHEN I ATTACH THIS EVENT
    search_type_combobox.attachEvent("onCheck", function(value, state){
        var values = search_type_combobox.getChecked();
        search_type_value = {};// put combo value into scope variable
        for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            search_type_value[values[i]] = true;// build hash for easy check later
            console.log(i);
            console.log(value);
            console.log(search_type_value);
            console.log(search_type_value[values[i]]);

        }
        gantt.render();// and repaint gantt
    });
    <!--Filter gantt by value of the scope variable-->
    gantt.attachEvent("onBeforeTaskDisplay", function (id, task) {
        if(search_type_value['ALL'])
            return true;
        return !!search_type_value[task.search_type];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the problem cannot be reconstructed locally.

If you are using an old version of the dhtmlxCombo (<4.4) please, try to "return true" from your onCheck event.

If the problem still occurs for you could you please, share a demo link, where the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Hi, @sematik, thanks for the reply, I'm using, dhtmlx 4.2, unfortunately i cant give you the test code because its confidential. but its almost practically the same other than the option is populated from my database using jinja for loop.

Comment: *dhtmlxGantt/Suite 4.2.

Comment: please, try to "return true" from your onCheck event

Comment: Hi @semantik thanks for your reply, rechecking my code it turns out Im using dhtmlxGantt, and not dhtmlxSuite there for the dhtmlxCombo code doesnt included in my project thank you for your help, much appreaciated